# Clipboard managers pasting in F# Interactive

Tags: visual-studio, clipboard, f#-interactive, clipboard-interaction

I have tried a few clipboard managers and two of the best (`Ditto` and `Ethervane Echo`) paste on an open F# Interactive window when I am trying to paste on the Editor. Others, like `ClipMate` (not free) paste on the Editor window. Is there a way to force pasting into the Editor window?

(I am aware that one can use `Ctrl+Shift+V` to cycle through recent clipboard items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Clip Angel clipboard manager. I use it for coding in C#. It pastes with no problem to C# interactive. And if you will meet some place where nothing can paste, Clip Angel has "Emulate keyboard input" feature to break the defence =).

Comment: I tried Clip Angel and it is a good clipboard manger. However, I am using Task View in Windows 10. If I 1) open Clip Angel in one View 2) switch to another view, 3) press Alt+V to bring up Clip Angel it stays open in the previous view and does not show up in the current view, so I cannot use it. Are you aware of a way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Try 1) "Settings / Fast window open" = ON 2) "Window/Show in taskbar" = OFF 3) "Settings / Fast window open" = OFF. If it will not help, I suggest you to write me  email (it is in About window of Clip Angel) with screenshots or create ticket on the site https://sourceforge.net/p/clip-angel/tickets/new/ .

Comment: What about Shapeshifter? (disclaimer: I am the author) https://github.com/ffMathy/Shapeshifter

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I found the following happens using `Ethervane Echo`.

1) In an `F#` solution:

a) Selecting an item in the clip list and hitting `Enter` sends the clip to `F# Interactive`.

b) Selecting an item in the clip list and double-clicking on it sends the clip to the Editor window.

2) In a `C#` solution:

Selecting an item in the clip list and either hitting `Enter` or double-clicking on it sends the clip to the Editor window.